# error rotating image by 90 in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, image, rotation, uiimage

I am using the following code to rotate an image -

```
- (UIImage *)rotateImage:(UIImage*)image byDegree:(CGFloat)degrees
{

UIView *rotatedViewBox = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,image.size.width,    image.size.height)];
CGAffineTransform t = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
rotatedViewBox.transform = t;
CGSize rotatedSize = rotatedViewBox.frame.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rotatedSize);
CGContextRef bitmap = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextTranslateCTM(bitmap, rotatedSize.width/2, rotatedSize.height/2);

    CGContextRotateCTM(bitmap, M_PI/2);
    CGContextScaleCTM(bitmap, 1.0, -1.0);

CGContextDrawImage(bitmap, CGRectMake(-image.size.width/2, -image.size.height/2, image.size.width, image.size.height), [image CGImage]);

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
```

}

My original image is - 
[image: image before rotate]

When I hit rotate, it does not rotate well - 
[image: image after rotate]

This kind of behavior happens only when the image is in the portrait mode i.e. (`image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft || image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight`) .  Landscape mode images are rotating well.

How can I edit the code to take care of both situations ?

Answer (score 0):

When your image is in portrait, do not apply the rotation (or apply a π-rotation). You do not need to change the `rotateImage` implementation, just the way you call it.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is problem with UIImageOrientationLeft and UIImageOrientationRight, all other i.e UIImageOrientationUp and UIImageOrientationDown comes the same way they looks.

I think there is no problem in the code, don’t use UIImageOrientationLeft and UIImageOrientationRight. Problem will be solved.

Comment: I am not using the UIIamgeOrientations in my code for rotation. When the image is landscape view ( width > height or photo clicked with phone horizontal ), code works well. However when the image is in portrait ( height > width or photo clicked with phone vertical), on first call to rotate, it distorts the image ( as shown in the second image) and then on subsequent calls, it rotates by 90 degrees ( in the same distorted view ).

Comment: The above code seems to be right, and there does not seem to be any error. And as you say the distortion appears only on the first call, this could also mean there is some other part of the code ( not shown here) which could be causing that distortion, following which the rotation is happening. 

I have checked the code, and it seems to be working fine for both portrait and landscape.